# Strange behaviour in <header> tag in Meteor + React

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am working through Meteor React tutorial.  In the code below when I change `<h1>` tag to `h2/h3/h4` the checkbox becomes unclickable (however `<b>` works) in all browsers (chrome, ff, ie). Is this an issue with React or Meteor or mine?

```
...
return (
  <div className="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Sample List</h1>  //changing to h2/h3/h4 makes checkbox unclickable

    <label className="hide-completed">
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        readOnly
        checked={this.state.hideCompleted}
        onClick={this.toggleHideCompleted.bind(this)}
        />
        Hide Completed Tasks
    </label>
    <form>...</form>
</header>
...
```

Comment: Could you please publish your code to github? It would help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Its an exact copy of Meteor todos, except <h1> in `App.jsx`

Comment: Less steps people need to reproduce your issue, more chances your question will be answered. So it would be nice of you to provide a link for todos example repo: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was solved by inserting a "br" between h1 and label.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    readOnly
    checked={this.state.hideCompleted}
    onClick={this.toggleHideCompleted.bind(this)}
    />
    Hide Completed Tasks
</label>

<br /> <!-- this one here-->

<form>...</form>
```

To find the answer I used the devTools in Chrome. Make a right click on the checkbox and choose "Inspect element". You'll most likely see that you selected the from below.
By inserting a "br" you avoid this problem, but it isn't the ideal solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to update your styles/CSS to reflect the new tag being used:

```
h2 /* from h1 to h2, for example */ {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```